# Using INSERT...RETURNING clause leads to ORA-12537

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net-managed

The problem is as simple as stated in question topic. I try to run some query using `INSERT...RETURNING` clause, which raises ORA-12537 exception when I try to execute it. The source is as follows:

```
using ( OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand () ) {
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.BindByName = true;
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO objects(name)VALUES(:objectName)RETURNING id INTO :objectId";
    command.Parameters.Add ( "objectName", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input );
    command.Parameters.Add ( "objectId", OracleDbType.Int64, ParameterDirection.Output );
    command.ExecuteNonQuery ();
}
```

Execution of the last line leads to OracleException being raised with message `ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file`. Running same query without `RETURNING` sub-clause goes obviously smooth.

Comment: Typo? You have to declare `:objectId` parameter (when `objectName` has been declared *twice*)

Comment: Yes, thanks, that's a typo I've made while typing my question. It isn't in the source.

Comment: @0xdb And you, kind sir, have my sincerest gratitude :) It'd be nice if you wrote that as an answer.

Comment: i've resolved simply with a space before "returning" ... 
VALUES(:objectName) RETURNING

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OracleCommand.CommandText` property sets the SQL statement or stored procedure to execute.
The ORA-12537 is an information message only and means that the connection has been closed. This can be caused by a number of reasons, i.a. oracle can't execute the sql statement properly and terminates the session.

Try to execute the statement as pl/sql block instead of in a pure sql context:

```
command.CommandText = @"
    begin 
        insert into objects(name) values(:objectName) returning id into :objectId; 
    end;";
```

Comment: It'd be nice to add that ODP.NET still allows to do just so, i.e. write something like `"BEGIN\nINSERT INTO objects(name)VALUES('somename')RETURNING id INTO :objectId;\nEND;"` and get returned value back from an output parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem too and initially used @0xdb solution and it worked.
Then, I found that the *ParameterDirection* should be *ReturnValue* and not *Output* and everything worked successfully.

```
using ( OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand () ) {
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.BindByName = true;
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO objects(name)VALUES(:objectName)RETURNING id INTO :objectId";
    command.Parameters.Add ( "objectName", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input );
    command.Parameters.Add ( "objectId", OracleDbType.Int64, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery ();
}
```